# Same file two different results

Tags: php

If I use this code

```
<?php
  include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/includes/header.php';
?>
```

I get the functions of the file im calling but do not get the layout/format or file images.

If I use this code

```
<?php
  $includeFile = file_get_contents("http://www.YourDomain.com/includes/header.php");
  echo $includeFile;
?>
```

I get the formatted layout but the search field does not function. Is there a way to combine the two codes to get the layout and the functions?

Comment: You're not supposed to delete that line at the bottom when you include an image.

Comment: Maybe you should check your question and explain what "this code" refers to :)

Comment: That is two very different things you're doing. The last one where you `file_get_contents` gets executed on the server, and only the HTML is returned.

Comment: `file_get_contents` will also grab any PHP source in the files and echo them to the client. That's a Bad Thing.

Comment: @Hamish: Not if you pass `file_get_contents` a URL.

Comment: @Rocket true, didn't look at the path. Generating your page by assembling output piped through http is pretty bad too :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/includes/header.php';
```

This basically copies and pastes that file into your file, and executes the PHP.

```
$includeFile = file_get_contents("http://www.YourDomain.com/includes/header.php");
echo $includeFile;
```

This runs the file like it was ran in your browser, and just echos the output, which is just HTML (probably).  In this case, the PHP was already executed and done.  In the first case, the PHP was executed and then PHP continues on.

Comment: Thanks for explaining the two actions! I was able to work through the problem after reading the comments made! I also looked into the security issues mentioned as well. :)

Answer (score 3):

When you "include" the file, you're essentially USING the code in the script calling it. If you are requesting the file with file_get_contents() , then it is processing the script and returning the output. I know what you're trying to do but the only way to do it is by including the main index.php file which then processes the rest of the script rather than try to re-process by requesting it from inside your second script.

Comment: yeah, this is basically a reworded version of Rocket's post